# Auto slideshow of images and videos

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slideshow, timertask

I'm trying to build an app that downloads media from the server (images and videos) and plays them in sequence like a slide show. for example, the app will show the first image for specific number of seconds then flips to the next one which could be an image (that will also play for some time) or it could be a short video which will flip to the next media once its finished.

I'm not sure how to tackle this, I'm hoping someone can put me in the right direction.

So far my app does all that only for images using TimerTask however, I now understand that I cannot make a TimeTask dynamic or change the Delay to match up the length of the video. The app wont serve its purpose if I have to kill the Timer function and re-initiate it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recycler view with child item ( hight and width as fullscreen, only one item is showing in screen) and inflate the layout resource based on media type like image/videos. After the delay, you can scroll the recycler view to the next item.

Comment: that's great. I'll look it up. Do you have any tutorials that you could recommend?

Comment: look into this  https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419#targetText=I%20was%20curious%20and%20began,big%20difference%20with%20the%20RecyclerView.